# ConnectionString that should work on all machine

Tags: wpf, database, connection-string

My WPF applicaiton uses database.In my app.copnfig I have set connectionstring as below :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AppointmentConnectionString" 
connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ClientAppointmentsDB;Integrated Security=true" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I have set data source to local(.),will this work on all machine ? If not,what should I do to make it work on all machine?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is SQL Server, `DataSource=local` (or `DataSource=.` or `DataSource=(local)` or `DataSource=localhost`) will only work if SQL Server is running on the same machine as the software and is the default instance, and has the same database name, and has the same security set-up (for `SSPI` Integrated Security) - as you can see, that's a lot of dependencies.

Often database-backed software will store the connection-string not in the `app.config` file (which is generally considered read-only, especially if a program is installed to a write-protected location like `%programfiles%`) - instead your software should prompt your user to specify the database server connection details and then save that in a simple configuration file under the user's `%appdata%` directory or local registry.

Make sure that if you're using an explicit username and password (instead of SSPI) that you adequately encrypt it, consider using DPAPI for per-user or per-machine encryption.